# How to center align a textview below imageview as a title in a List view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not able to align a text below imageview in a listview. below is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"     >

    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />


    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and ListView is

```
<ListView    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="280sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgView"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:gravity="center" >
</ListView>
```

java code to dynamically add text and image from array

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.imageName.setText(name[position]);
        holder.image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

not getting how to center text below imageview. please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [`layout_centerHorizontal`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerHorizontal) attribute in your TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Thanks for quick  response @Sam but no success. text still coming right align not centered  :( .

Comment: I see, two choices: either change your RelativeLayout's width to `wrap_content` or change your ImageView's width to `match_parent`.

Comment: After changing ImageView's width to match_parent it works. Thanks a lot @Sam for your valuable help.

Comment: No trouble, please click the checkmark in my answer to show that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In textview change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Linear layout to set orientation attribute. Set orientation to vertical for Linear layout  and set imageview attribute `android:layout_gravity="center"`
Here is the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/home" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cardiology"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

hope it will help