# How to center align TextView below another TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, centering

Currently my XML looks like the following:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is have 'Day' (which gets replaced with actual day (e.g. 03, 24)) horizontally centered below month (where in 'Month' also gets replaced with a MMM formatted month string) such that the horizontal center of day matches the horizontal center of month. To the side are some other TextView objects such as the event name and event time.

I based my XML in part off of [How to center align a textview below imageview as a title in a List view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825033/how-to-center-align-a-textview-below-imageview-as-a-title-in-a-list-view) but day is slightly too far to the right and I'm not quite sure how to remedy the issue despite fiddling around with attributes from the RelativeLayout docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

events_info.xml (layout for ListView objects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/eventsRelLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Month" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/month"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Day" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/month"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/month"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text="Time" />
```

fragment_event_list.xml (ListView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="fish.glow.EventFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="month month" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/month"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="day" />

</RelativeLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_left"
    android:text="name" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_left"
    android:text="time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This places month in upper left, day in upper right (should be in lower left), name in lower left (should be in upper right), and time in lower right.

Comment: This makes both day and month horizontally aligned to the left. I'm trying to get day to be horizontally aligned in the center of month. Sorry for any confusion. :X

Comment: In other words, I want the horizontal center of day to match horizontal center of month

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/eventsRelLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:orienation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Month" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/month"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Day" />
</LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text="Time" />
```